Why would two different sized bikes not arrive at the same time starting from rest on the same slope?
I was cycling with my little sister who was a little upset by the fact that I would arrive first at the end of a small bridge when we both started from the middle (where the plane is not inclined).
Once we arrived home our dad told her that there was nothing to complain about as I am heavier than her.
I am pretty sure my dad is incorrect as g, the gravitational acceleration is the same for my sister and I, however I can't figure out the right answer.
Let's say hypothetically that we were next to each other, at rest, and began descending at the same time for a straight inclined plane.
Now could the size of the wheels actually make me get down faster? I guess that having smaller wheels means that it would require many more revolutions to travel the same distance.
Just to clarify the bikes are simply rolling. Because of the different size of the bikes it is likely that the gear ratio may be different.
I am aware that there are many different variables to consider. For example the pressure of the tyres: which should be supposed to be sufficient to make the tyres decently filled with air.

"I guess that having smaller wheels means that it would require many more revolutions to travel the same distance." It's true smaller wheels would have to revolve faster to go the same speed. However, that only matters if you're pedaling, please clarify by editing your question. When coasting the wheels spin free, the ground turns the wheels powered by gravity and inertia. However, friction does come into play, spinning faster means more friction on both the wheel/road and wheel/axle.

See Which is more efficient: a larger wheel or a smaller wheel? And it's also why an airplane can take off on a conveyor belt, the wheels are not powered and roll free.

@Schwern A smaller wheel size means a shorter, and thus wider contact patch with the road. And a wider contact patch means more massaging of rubber, i.e. more rolling resistance. I don't think this effect is relevant here, though.

To clarify - you're both coasting, without any pedalling?   And you are older, therefore likely heavier than your sister?  And the two bikes have the same tyre pressures and tyre widths etc ?

@Criggie even with the same pressures and widths, kids' bikes almost always have rubbish tyres (as do a lot of cheap adult bikes of the hybrid to light MTB type, even if otherwise better than BSOs)

The key thing to remember is: always let your little sister win.

@SimonCrase never! I am too competitive makes it more fun XD

Try switching bikes with your sister and see if the results change. This should help identify the difference that occurs because of differences in rider mass and air drag.

The main force slowing down a fast moving bicycle is air drag.
When you're rolling down a slope, gravity is speeding up your bike while drag is slowing it down.  The force of gravity is proportional to your mass (plus that of your bicycle) while the drag force is proportional to your frontal area and approximately proportional to the square of your speed relative to the air.
Yes, there's also some friction in the wheel bearings and some rolling drag between the wheels and the ground.  Like gravity, rolling drag is typically also proportional to weight, so if it was the only thing slowing your bike down, you would indeed expect the weight of the rider not to matter.
However, at speeds above about 20 km/h or so air drag will exceed rolling drag, and even at lower speeds (unless you're going very slowly or driving in deep mud or snow, or unless your bike is super rusty and never oiled) the effect of air drag is still noticeable.  (That's also why it's so much harder to drive a bicycle against the wind than with the wind behind you.)
Thus there is still a significant component to the total drag force that's not proportional to your mass but to your frontal area.
For two objects of similar shape and composition, such as two humans, mass is approximately proportional to volume, and thus to height cubed, while frontal area is only proportional to height squared.  Thus, the ratio of gravitational to drag force (at a given velocity) for a bicyclist rolling down a hill is approximately proportional to their height, or to the cube root of their weight.  (This is yet another example of a square–cube law.)
While this relationship is only approximate (since obviously human bodies are not all the same shape and two equally tall people can have different body weights), it still holds pretty well, especially when comparing a small child to an adult (or an adolescent).
So if e.g. your little sister is 120 cm tall and you're 180 cm, your gravity-to-air-drag ratio at a given speed is about 1.5 times that of your sister (and your equilibrium speed at which drag and gravity are balanced will be about $\sqrt{1.5} ≈ 1.2$ times that of your sister's, assuming a sufficiently steep hill for air drag to dominate rolling drag).
In other words, your dad was right.  In an atmosphere, all else being equal, heavier objects really do fall (and roll) down faster.

"The main force slowing down a fast moving bicycle is air drag." - True, but from rest you'd need quite a hill to get to a suitable value of "fast"  (rolling resistance dominates below about 20km/h)

Surely objects fall at the same speed regardless of mass. Yes, gravitational force is greater but that is exactly offset by the force having to act on a greater mass. Acceleration due to gravity does not depend on mass.

@SteveIves: In a vacuum, yes. In an atmosphere, no, because gravity is not the only force involved.

@ChrisH: "quite a hill"? In my commute there is a slope of about 10% gradient and about 80 meters long. If I arrive at the slope doing 10km/h, without pedaling I'll be doing 30km/h at the bottom.

@MartinArgerami the question states starting at rest, not 10 km/h.  From rest, even on your hill most of the descent would be done at speeds where rolling resistance is greater than drag.  10% is pretty steep so it's not surprising that you get up to a decent speed given how much potential energy you start with.  A gentler slope means much more distance travelled to get up to speed, during which you can lose more energy to RR and drag

I seriously doubt that we are talking about speeds higher than 20 km/h. Also, some equations supporting the discussion of the gravity-to-drag ration could be helpful. In absence of drag and friction the two bikes have the same acceleration, so naively it is hard to see how drag, smaller for the smaller rider, would make the smaller bike move faster.

@MartinArgerami 10% grade is very steep already. And I doubt the two riders in the story got anywhere near 30 km/h.

See my answer for a mechanism explaining why a heavier rider will roll down faster even in a vacuum, and at low speeds (comparing two riders on identical bikes).

It's all about the air drag. Anyone who has skied a schuss (a long, slightly inclined slope where you just cruise and don't slalom) will notice that the kids are always being passed by the heavier adults (I whizz past everyone...). It's just terminal velocity, which goes up with weight.

For a decent quality bike the friction of the wheel bearings will be fairly irrelevant but for a for a low end bike it is not. I once used this rolling down a hill experiment to convince someone that there is indeed a major difference between a 600 $ bike from a bike store and a 150 $ bike from Walmart (prices 20 years ago).

It is not clear from the description, if the bikes are simply rolling or if the pedals are used. Different gear ratios could easily account for the difference in the latter case, while in the former it is mostly the interplay between friction and the moment of inertia of a rotating wheel (which depends on its size.)
The following image shows forces acting on the wheel rolling downhill:
(image source)

There is a static friction force (denoted as simply Friction force in the image), which is limited by the maximum possible value for no slipping:
$$
\text{Friction force }\leq \mu N=\mu Mg\cos\theta
$$
If the friction force exceeds the critical value, slipping occurs. As the critical value is not the same for the two bikes, with the riders and the bikes themselves having different masses, slipping of a smaller bike wheels could account for the disparity.
The rolling friction force (named Drag force in the image) is also proportional to the mass:
$$
\text{Drag force }=\mu N = \mu Mg\cos\theta,
$$
however the friction coefficient itself is dependent on the wheel parameters. Wikipedia even proposes two different formulas for it - inversely proportional to the wheel radius and to the square root of the wheel radius($C_{rr}=\sqrt{z/d}$ and $F=C_{rr}N=bN/r$). This suggests that heavier rider would experience higher friction force... but the numerical value of the prefactor would be also different for the two bikes or even for the identical bikes with the wheels having different pressure.
Finally, when wheel starts rotation, there is friction between the wheel and its axis, in other words, the Newton's equation for the rotation speed would become something like:
$$
I\frac{d\omega}{dt}=-\gamma\omega + r\times\text{ Friction force},
$$
where the moment of inertia is proportional to the radius of the wheel squared: $I\propto r^2$.
To conclude: I wouldn't make bets on which bike rolls faster, so I have doubts about the explanation provided in the Q (Once we arrived home our dad told her that there was nothing to complain about as I am heavier than her.) But expecting that they arrive at different times is quite reasonable.
Update
Some of the answers and comments have focused on the air drag, as the main factor slowing down the bikes. IMHO, although the air drag is certainly a factor, claiming that it dominates requires quantitative estimates that no one provided (for the air drag and the alternatives outlined above in this answer.) Without making definitive claims I suggest a few points to consider:

As bicycles start from zero velocity, I seriously doubt that their speed at the end of the bridge is as high as 20 km/h or more, where the air drag becomes important.
The linear drag is independent on the mass (see the derivation here and Stoke's law), whereas quadratic drag starts to play role at higher velocities (see terminal velocity.)


Of course the bikes are simply rolling. Because of the different size of the bikes it is likely that the gear ratio may be different.

-1: the physics in the answer is right, but the answer ignores air resistance which is likely the main factor. In bicycle racing, it is well-known that heavier riders have an advantage on the downhills.

@MartinArgerami If you suggested including air resistance (instead of downvoting), I would have done so. I didn't include it, because I don't think it is important here: the speeds are low and the distance is small (unlike in bicycle races.) If you think that air resistance is the most important factor here - I challenge you to write an answer and prove it with data and numbers, as a physicist should. (I chose to avoid making such definitive claims in my answer.)

It depends. Here are my thoughts: In general, you have to take into account the moment of inertia for rolling objects. The object with a bigger moment of inertia will accelerate slower, if they have the same dimensions, i.e. same shape but different distribution of the mass. For different sized wheels have a look at this post here. The two cylinders with different radii have the same speed for any height $h$. So from that I would conclude that the reason is not different sized wheels.
Regarding the weights: You are right that both of you are accelerated by $g$ in the same way. But in principle, the lighter you are, the more air resitance will play a role. So the final velocity of heavier objects is always higher. Compare a feather falling vs a rock. I am not sure that this is the reason. But you can just check. Let your sister use your bike and see if she is as fast as you or slower. (Compared to you on your bike; take the time) Posture is of course also important regarding the air resitance.
My best guess would actually be that the friction in the bearing is the important point. If it is old bike vs new, then the new one might have a better chance.

As i am bigger wouldn't my body be affected by more air resistance considering the bigger area? Does mass affect air resistance that much?

Re, "friction in the bearing." Haven't done the research, but my bet would be that the rolling resistance of the tires plays a much bigger role than any resistance from the wheel bearings. Especially so if the bike has fat, off-road tires, or if the tires are under-inflated.

@serax If we assume your body densities are equivalent, a larger person has smaller surface area to mass ratio.  The exact calculation of that is too complex to get into but to get a rough idea of this, you can take, e.g. a golf ball and a ping pong ball and try to throw them as far as possible. The golf ball is larger and heavier, so why can you throw it so much farther? The answer is related to inertia.

@JimmyJames Hey, we found a positive use for the cube/square law. Yay!

@Corey Well, assuming that people are spherical, the rest follows.

Presumably the speeds were rather modest, so ignoring air drag. I have seen something similar when riding with my wife (roughly half of my weight). I cannot vouch for the frictions to be equal (my bike is newer, and probably better maintained). But consider the following effect that kicks in already at the lowest speeds (unlike air drag).
Imagine a rider with mass $M$ on a bike with mass $m$, and wheels with moment of inertia $I$ and radius $R$. The total kinetic energy of this system, travelling at speed $v$ (hence with the wheels rotating at angular speed $\omega=v/R$, no slipping) is
$$E=\frac12Mv^2+\frac12mv^2+\frac12(I/R^2)v^2.$$
Assume that all of the gravitational potential energy of the system, $V=(M+m)gh$, $h$ the difference in elevation, is converted into kinetic energy (ignoring friction, too). We arrive at the equation
$$
v^2\left(\frac12(M+m)+\frac12(I/R^2)\right)=(M+m)gh.
$$
Solving for $v^2$ gives
$$
v^2=2gh-\frac{2I/R^2}{M+m+I/R^2}gh.
$$
Look at the extra term with the minus sign. It accounts for the difference from free falling from height $h$. With two riders of different masses $M$ on identical bikes (so the same $m, I,R$) we see that the heavier rider ends up going faster simply because with a heavier rider a smaller fraction of the available energy is wasted in the rotational energy term $\frac12I\omega^2$.

See the comments by Ilmari Karonen under this answer for an explanation as to why using wheel mass as a substitute for $I/R^2$ is a fair approximation. This leads us to the following way of testing whether this effect is real: two riders of the same size (so equal air drag) roll down a hill. Bike frames are also "equal", but one is riding a regular bike while the other rides a fatbike. Who will win? According to the posters who think air drag is the only factor it would be a draw, right?

I'm not convinced that this "fits the observation better than air drag / mass ratio": if the OP and their sister went fast enough and far enough to meaningfully race each other, they probably went fast enough for air drag to matter too (even if other effects might not have been negligible). And the OP never actually said they started from a standstill — that was just part of their thought experiment. All that said, the effect you describe could very well have also contributed. +1 for noticing it and for a very nice analysis.

@IlmariKaronen I do concede that we need more accurate numbers to decide. I did assume identical bicycles, which is unlikely to be the case, and "a vacuum". Anyway, with my wife, the bikes have more or less the same mass, and same size wheels. Still, there are also other reasons why I roll down a small hill faster than she will (age of bikes,...). Very difficult to take everything into account.

Removing the last paragraph. As Ilmari pointed out, we don't have enough observations to back up the claim in the first edition of my answer.

And, I know that with zero friction there might be no rolling, just sliding, I have hit icy patches often enough :-)

I was curious how big this effect would be, so I tried plugging in some numbers. First of all, most of the mass of a bicycle wheel is in the rim (+ tube) and in the hub. Ignoring the hub (which has a negligible diameter), spokes (which have negligible mass) and the thickness of the rim and the tube (which overestimates the rotational inertia), we can let $I = m_W R^2$, where $m_W$ is the total mass of the wheel rims and tubes. Thus $I/R^2$ simplifies to just $m_W$, so the fraction of total energy that goes into wheel rotation is just $m_W / (M + m + m_W)$. (Note that $m$ includes $m_W$!) […]

… Now, to plug in some numbers, let's assume the OP and their sister were riding fatbikes with really heavy rims and tubes. Based on some Googling, those rims might weigh up to 1 kg each, while the tubes might weigh up to 0.5 kg on top of that, for $m_W$ = 3 kg. Meanwhile, let's assume the OP's sister is a skinny 6-year-old and weighs $M$ = 20 kg, and just to be generous let's neglect the bike frame's weight and let $m = m_W$. With those generous assumptions, about 11.5% of the total energy goes into wheel rotation, reducing $v$ by about 6%. Which, to be fair, is indeed not negligible.

… Of course, for more realistic scenarios the effect is likely to be smaller. One way to intuitively gauge how much smaller (if you happen to have your bicycle handy) is to flip the bike upside down (like you'd do e.g. when taking the wheels off to fix a puncture), turn the pedals to spin the rear wheel up and then press the brake to stop it. Then compare how hard you had to brake and and how fast the wheel stopped compared to how much it would take to brake from a comparable speed when riding the bike. (Either that, or just weigh yourself and your bike frame and rims and do the math.)

Thanks for the numbers, @Ilmari. Yeah, this effect is not very large. OTOH, it doesn't have to be large to annoy the little sister.

I vaguely recal having read a claim that at 40 km/h something like 80-90% of the energy of a bicyclist goes towards winning the air drag. Of course that is proportional to the square of the speed. I was mentally imagining something like 10-15 km/h max for a little sister. But even then air drag would be at a comparable level.

-1 for ignoring air drag. It is air drag that is entirely responsible for the observed phenomenon. The same thing happens when skiing a schuus - where there is no radius, moment of inertia, rotation or any of the other stuff that is confusing you.

@OscarBravo Vote however you see fit. I have cycled over 13000km over last 6 years, and know enough about air drag being the main obstruction at my speeds (20 km/h or so) unless climbing, that is. The mental image of the situation here is A) starting from standstill, and B) dropping 5ft of elevation. When the speed is close to zero, air drag is negligible, whereas this phenomenon effectively means that the two riders experience slightly different values of $g$ (depending on the mass of the wheels, as Ilmari explained).

This may not be the answer you are looking for on Physics SE, but...
A correct answer that hasn't been posted yet is:

The smaller bike is a child's bicycle.
The larger bike is an adult's bicycle.
Toys for children (that can be ridden) have more friction in the wheels as a safety feature.

Friction is physics... so don't let it be said that there's no physics in this answer :-)

An experiment to verify this answer: on a flat surface, accelerate to the same speed (side by side) and you both take your feet off the pedals. If she coasts as far as you do, downvote me.

Something like this may play a role. But don't know if the difference is a safety measure. An adult's bike costs more and often is designed to last longer. Therefore more care and effort is put into manufacturing it. Also, a child's bike may simple be less well maintained, worn out bearings, underinflated tyres etc. I see this when riding with my wife. We coast down a modest incline, and I gain distance on her. Guess I should by new bearings for her bike,  pack and grease them well etc :-)

@JyrkiLahtonen Valid input. For clarity, the increased friction I'm referring to in all of the riding child toys (that my children had) is proportional to the target age. The lower the age, the higher the friction is likely to be. I first noticed this when my daredevil went down the driveway on a "Cozy Coupe" ride-on toy. The only clues we have on the age of the younger child is "little sister" and the fact that they both still appear to live with their parents. If his little sister is a teenager, your explanation is more likely. If the little sister is under the age of 9, mine may be right.

I broadly agree with the other answers, but I think they get into the weeds a bit and this can be explained much more directly. There are 3 forces acting on the bike: gravity, the normal force which keeps the bike from dropping through the ground and friction.
$$
\sum F = m \vec a = m \vec g \sin \theta + \vec N \cos \theta - \beta f(\vec v )
$$
The normal force, barring jumps, acts perpendicular to the velocity of the cyclist, so we can ignore it. Gravity and acceleration are both proportional to the mass of the cyclist, but friction is not. We model different frictions in different ways, but it always acts opposite the direction of travel and it is not proportional to the mass. Therefore, when we simplify by dividing by $m$, we find
$$
\vec a = \vec g \sin \theta - \frac{\beta}{m} f(\vec v)
$$
that as mass increases, the friction matters less and less. It is not qualitatively important where the friction comes from: I've seen better-skilled child skiers travel much more slowly than their adult counterparts, especially on high snow-friction days. If you were modeling cyclists to get precise and accurate predictions, getting into the weeds with friction would matter, but there are so many variables - bike quality, how well each bike is tuned/oiled, tire profile, drag coefficients, rider profiles ... the full list would be exhaustive. The bottom line is that friction matters more for feathers than bowling balls.

But in simple models for friction, isn't it proportional to the normal force which is proportional to mass, so $m$ cancels out? See "Is a heavier skier faster?", "Does a ski racer with a larger mass have an advantage?", and "Skiing downhill".

@DavidBailey there are lots of friction models, and all of them are sort of bad in that they can do an ok job of describing one situation, but none do a great job at describing all situations. While sliding friction (for skiing) depends on the mass (unlike air resistance) it may not be a linear dependence. There are wildly different curves for friction as a function of speed depending on snow conditions as well - if it's too cold, snow doesn't melt under a skier's pressure, and if it's too warm, the water's surface tension starts slowing things down.

@DavidBailey Also, literally none of your links show mass "cancelling out" unless you naively consider $\rho$ to be something other than a [nearly] constant property of animal biomass.

I certainly agree that tribology is a very challenging science, but don't understand why combining friction and air resistance in a single "$-\beta f(\vec v )$" term is helpful here.   I only referred to the skiing questions since that was the example you gave. Their answers emphasize the importance of air resistance (which gives the $\rho$ term that is not proportional to $m$). I certainly would agree with a statement that "air resistance matters more for feathers than bowling balls", but the situation with friction is less clear, e.g. if the interface is shear thickening, deformable, ….

@DavidBailey Because there are a lot of factors that come into play that are all dependent on some function of velocity and which act opposite velocity. The $f(v)$ covers all of them, and you're right that the $\beta$ term is completely unnecessary. Are there systems you can think of where the child would go faster?

@user121330 absolutely. Riding on a clay that yields under the stress applied by the adult, but remains elastic when ridden on by the child. Sand might behave similarly but it's less clear. It's unlikely that these effects are in play in this case, but there certainly are friction forces that are super-linear with respect to normal force, and right now the formulation of $f$ implies it's not a function of mass, or surface area.

Since you and your sister have different bikes with different wheel sizes, the moment of inertia for the wheels may be different and this will affect the acceleration.

The sum of the forces tangent to the slope give the acceleration of the center of mass:
$$ma_{cm} = mg\sin\theta - F_f$$
The sum of the torques about the center of mass give the angular acceleration of the wheel. The only force that produces torque is the rolling friction:
$$I\alpha = F_fr$$ where I is the moment of inertia and r is the radius of the wheel. For pure rolling (no slipping):
$$ a_{cm} = \alpha r$$ and
$$F_f = \frac{Ia_{cm}}{r^2}$$
Substituting and solving for $a_{cm}$ leaves:
$$a_{cm} = \frac{mg\sin\theta}{m + \frac {I}{r^2}}$$
The smaller the moment of inertia of the wheel, the greater the acceleration of the center of mass.
Most bicycle wheels are not solid disks. They are annular in shape:

The moment of inertia is:
$$I = \frac 1 2 m(r_i^2 + r^2)$$ where $r_i$ is the inner radius of the wheel.
Substituting gives:
$$a_{cm} = \frac{g\sin\theta}{1+\frac 1 2 (1+\frac{r_i^2}{r^2})}$$
Note that the acceleration is not dependent on the mass. All that is needed is to calculate is the radii of the wheels.
My guess is that your bike has both a larger radius and thinner wheels ( rim plus tires) which gives your bike an advantage.
